# How to "Scan for hosts" only using ettercap CLI?

Tags: network, network-scanners, ettercap

I've been looking for a command to "Scan for hosts" in the terminal with ettercap CLI.

How can I scan the local subnet from the ettercap terminal?

The graphical ettercap has the options (see below):

[image]

Comment: Have you red [man ettercap](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ettercap) ?

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I can’t find the option.

Comment: From the description “—silent” don’t seem fit.

Answer (score 1):

In curses mode, `ettercap -C`, use *Menu* > *"Unified sniffing"* first. Then *Menu* > *Hosts* > *"Scan for hosts"*

[image]

In Text mode, `ettercap -T`, you can use the  `-n, --netmask <NETMASK>` option for the network mask.